# vagrant provisioning fails mentioning object not found

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

When I am executing vagrant up or vagrant provision, it fails with the below error. Any suggestion to fix this is welcome. Where is the `vagrant-7343223c` created in

```
#<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: hefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-7343223c>
```

The  above  line is taken from the error log given below.

```
==> local: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
    local: Installing Chef (latest)...
==> local: Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> local: Running chef-solo...
==> local: stdin: is not a tty
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:50-07:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/vagrant-chef/695f45722c929d836cb98d5599d7becf
==> local:   One version per cookbook
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:50-07:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> local: Starting Chef Client, version 12.11.1
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:50-07:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.11.1 ***
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:50-07:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:50-07:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2877
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:51-07:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/vagrant-7343223c
==> local: [2016-05-19T02:12:51-07:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-7343223c>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's been a few [issues](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4948) reported since yesterday - the solution seems to downgrade chef to 12.10.24

In your Vagrantfile just mention the chef version to use

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.version = "12.10.24"
  end
end
```